# Android webview centering horizontal and vertical

Tags: android, webview, center

I'm new to Android development, and trying to center text and images using web view.  I've tried

```
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
```

and it's not centering vertically or horizontally.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: do you want to center the content, that is displayed by the WebView?

Comment: Yes I want to center the content, some of the content is text and some of it is images, thanks!

Comment: How did you do at the end? XD